# Shared application data on Mac?

Tags: macos

I'm new to building application on Mac. I have global data that I need to share between users and not sure where to store this data on Mac to avoid permissions issues when reading and writing files.

On Windows I have stored it in /ProgramData/ in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changeable goes in /Library/Application Support/application-name however note you will need to ask for an admin username and password.

If the data is never change or only at install then it can be held inside the Application bundle.

Read all about this in the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/WhereToPutFiles.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001411-BAJHCHJI)

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link, both are extremely useful. My only remaining question is what happens in the situation where you need an application to write a file which can then be written to be other users also?

Is there a way to do this without pushing for admin user/pass? An example which comes to mind is a spellcheck dictionary: if you wanted a user to be able to add a word, then another user to see that change if they booted up the application.

Comment: You can create a file that is writeable by all by changing the file attributes on a file